# Transfering data form2 radiobutton to form4 label in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two radio buttons in form2 and if one of them is checked, I want to display information in a label in form4. please help

Here is what I have :

```
    Public Class Form4

    Public Form2 As New Object
       Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       If Me.Form2.RadioButton1 = CheckState.Checked Then
        Label2.Text = "You have been successfully registered for the following modules                  in the first semester."
    Else
        Label2.Text = "You have been successfully registered for the following modules in the second semester."
    End If
```

Comment: Start by turning on `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit`. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329

Comment: Then you can use either **Checkedchange** event or **Click** event of RadioButton in Form2 and in that event open Form4 by passing status of radiobutton in the constructor of Form4 event and display message as per your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way:-

Form 2

```
Public Class Form2
  Dim check As Integer = 0

   Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
       check = 1
     Else
       check = 0 
    End If
End Sub

   Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
       check = 2
     Else
       check = 0 
    End If
End Sub

    Public Function sendCheck() As Integer
    return check
    End Function

End Class
```

Form 4

```
  Public Class Form4

  Dim receivedCheck As Integer = Form2.sendCheck


   Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  If receivedCheck = 1 Then

    Label2.Text = "You have been successfully registered for the following modules in the first semester."

   ElseIf receivedCheck = 2 Then

    Label2.Text = "You have been successfully registered for the following modules in the second semester."

  End If
  End Sub
  End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

The error you may be getting in is the condition in `If` statement. What you have done is, you have used `Me` ahead of Form2. `Me` is used to refer objects within the form and for referring to other forms we use their name.

Remember, a form can never call itself with its name. It will call itself by `Me`. But here, you have used both `Me` and `Form2` (Which means Form2 is an object within Form4) which we don't have to do.

So, remove the two letters `Me` and your program will work fine.

But, it would be better if you generate a `checkedchanged` event. This is how I would have written it, but you can write anyways you want, just the main problem that you may be getting was the use of `Me` and `Form2` both.

This is how I would have written it:

## Code And Example

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub CheckedChanged () Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
         If Form2.RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
                Label2.Text = "You have been successfully registered for the following modules                  in the first semester."
         Else
                Label2.Text = "You have been successfully registered for the following modules in the second semester."
         End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

I hope that you will understand!

Comment: I understand a little, and i have now removed the Me keyword but still it gives me an error along this line of code: If Form2.RadioButton1.Checked = True Then, during runtime. And another thing, the radiobuttons are in form2 and the labels are in form4 and  I want the messages to display when form4 loads.

Comment: What is the error? I know you want to display when the form loads but you can do it either way. This is not a messagebox that it would pop out whenever the command is executed. It's a label and will be shown only when form4 is shown.

Comment: It says "object variable or With Block is not set"